# How to keep a UIView always showing over multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib, addsubview

I wish to create and present a view over each view controller in my app allowing users to interact with it or the view controllers beneath it. I want the view to always appear on top of whatever view I may present or segue to.

I have a custom UIView that appears when users tap a table view cell. Within the didSelectRowAt tableView function I have tried:

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.addSubview(self.subView!)
```

and

```
self.view.addSubview(self.subView!)
```

Both function similarly with the view appearing over the current View controller and allowing users to interact with the table still. But when I present a new ViewController the subView disappears as it has not been added to the new View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `UIWindow`, and override `addSubview()` to make sure your overlay view is always on top:

```
weak var overlay: MyOverlayView!

override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
    if let overlay = view as? MyOverlayView {
        self.overlay = overlay 
        super.addSubview(overlay)
    } else {
        self.insertSubview(view, belowSubview: overlay)
    }
}
```

You must make sure the app delegate uses your custom class as the app's main window, and not the superclass `UIWindow`. For this, remove the "Main storyboard file base name" entry from your Info.plist and instead instantiate the main window manually in your AppDelegate:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: MyCustomWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        self.window = MyCustomWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        // 1. Add your overlay view to the window
        // (...)

        // 2. Load your initial view controller from storyboard, or 
        //  instantiate it programmatically
        // (...)

        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

*Note: I haven't tested this code. Let me know in the comments if there's a problem.*

Comment: I had to make the else part of the addSubview override just ```super.addSubview(view)``` but it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!